# sending Email with attachement using Javamail on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-mail

I want to send email with attachement ( a pptx file for example )
I have the path of the file in my database and I want to get it and send an email containing the file (not the path of the file ) . 
I have downloaded the **java.mail.jar** , the **activation.jar** and also the **MySQL-connector-java-bin.jar** .
The error shows when I add the **java.mail.jar**  . 
Below is a picture summarising all the story : 
[image]

Comment: Looks like Eclipse is broken and is getting a NullPointerException while building your project.  Report the bug to Eclipse.  You may have made a mistake in your code or your project, but a NullPointerException is not a valid response to that mistake.  In the mean time, try building outside of Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  My code has no mistakes but it may need some optimisations . I wrote it in netbeans and it worked with no problem at all ! .

Comment: Great!  Please report the bug to Eclipse.